# How do you add/include header row and totals row from a pivot table in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, openpyxl

I'm working on exporting data via PySpark to Excel. I have a data set

```
df_raw = spark.createDataFrame([("2015-10", 'U.S.', 500), \
                                ("2018-10", 'Germany', 580), \
                                ("2019-08", 'Japan', 230), \
                                ("2015-12", 'U.S.', 500), \
                                ("2015-11", 'Germany', 580), \
                                ("2015-12", 'Japan', 502), \
                                ("2018-10", 'U.S.', 520), \
                                ("2019-08", 'Canada', 200)]).toDF("ym", "country", "points")
+-------+-------+------+
|     ym|country|points|
+-------+-------+------+
|2015-10|   U.S.|   500|
|2018-10|Germany|   580|
|2019-08|  Japan|   230|
|2015-12|   U.S.|   500|
|2015-11|Germany|   580|
|2015-12|  Japan|   502|
|2018-10|   U.S.|   520|
|2019-08| Canada|   200|
+-------+-------+------+
```

that I convert to a pivot table

```
df_pivot = df_raw.groupBy('country').pivot("ym").sum('points')
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|country|2015-10|2015-11|2015-12|2018-10|2019-08|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|Germany|   null|    580|   null|    580|   null|
|   U.S.|    500|   null|    500|    520|   null|
| Canada|   null|   null|   null|   null|    200|
|  Japan|   null|   null|    502|   null|    230|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

and I would like to export the table with the header row and a row for grand totals into an Excel spreadsheet via `Openpyxl`.

I can loop through the dataframe using `.collect()` and append the records to a worksheet but it doesn't include the header and I would like to add a grand total row as well.

Example of the grand total row:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|country|2015-10|2015-11|2015-12|2018-10|2019-08|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|Germany|   null|    580|   null|    580|   null|
|   U.S.|    500|   null|    500|    520|   null|
| Canada|   null|   null|   null|   null|    200|
|  Japan|   null|   null|    502|   null|    230|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|       |    500|    580|   1002|   1100|    430|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at the `rollup` function and unioning it afterwards, e.g.

```
df = df_raw.groupBy('country').pivot("ym").sum('points')
df2 = df.rollup('country').count()
```

Alternatively, just take the output of your pivot, dynamically select the date columns (on a regex pattern or something) and aggregate them with `sum()`, and alias back into the column name.

EDIT:
Now I understand what exactly you wanted. I would still use `rollup` but combined with some renaming and union, such as:

```
from functools import reduce

agg_cols = df_pivot.columns[1:]
rollup_df = df_pivot.rollup().sum()

renamed_df = reduce(
    lambda rollup_df, idx: rollup_df.withColumnRenamed(rollup_df.columns[idx], agg_cols[idx]), 
    range(len(rollup_df.columns)), rollup_df
)

renamed_df = renamed_df.withColumn('country', f.lit('Total'))

df_pivot.unionByName(
    renamed_df
).show()
```

Output:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|country|2015-10|2015-11|2015-12|2018-10|2019-08|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|Germany|   null|    580|   null|    580|   null|
|   U.S.|    500|   null|    500|    520|   null|
| Canada|   null|   null|   null|   null|    200|
|  Japan|   null|   null|    502|   null|    230|
|  Total|    500|    580|   1002|   1100|    430|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

*Tested on PySpark 2.4.3*

Comment: `rollup()` appears to only work with counts running left to right. I'm looking to get a summation of each column as well as include the header row when exporting to a list.

Comment: I see. Still use `rollup()` but use it with some renaming and `unionByName()`. I modified the original answer to include the code.